# Use Bootstrap Modal in React

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am having trouble using a Bootstrap modal in ReactJS. My code renders the console.log function just fine, but it will not show the modal. Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class ExternalLink extends React.Component {

  renderModal() {
    console.log("the link " + this.props.url + " was clicked.")

    return (
      <div className="modal show">
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal 
              title</h5>

              <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" 
              aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              ...
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data- 
               dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Save 
              changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>,

      document.getElementById("root")
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a onClick={() => this.renderModal()}>{this.props.url}</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ExternalLink;
```

Since the Javascript seems to work, I'm thinking I did something wrong in the Bootstrap area of things. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how react works. You can't render something from an event handler. What you do is set up some state to control what gets rendered. In your example:

```
class ExternalLink extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { showModal: false }
  }

  renderModal() {
    console.log("the link " + this.props.url + " was clicked.")

    return (
      <div className="modal show">
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal 
              title</h5>

              <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" 
              aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              ...
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data- 
               dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Save 
              changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a onClick={() => this.setState({showModal: true})}>{this.props.url}</a>
        {this.state.showModal && this.renderModal()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Your `renderModal` method should just be a separate component. Note that you'll have to put some way to set `showModal` to false in your modal to hide it again.